# Automate reset password in wordpress (python requests or other ways)

Tags: wordpress, forms, authentication, python-requests, change-password

I am trying to take some measurements about how fast is resetting a user's password with the default WordPress methods. WordPress first asks for an email or the username, and then sends a link to the email of that user. If you follow the link, it redirects you to a page ("localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-login.php?action=rp") where you must insert a new password for that that user. It looks like that:
[Provide new password image (default content on the password field)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tLTH.png)

I have the ability to do some small changes to the WordPress code (for example I changed the wp_mail function so no mail is sent and added some storing of the activation link in a specific file). I need to do experiments with a lot of users trying to change their passwords at the same time. I have written code using Selenium about it, but this is not what I am looking for, because it is slow. I am trying to find out if there is a quicker solution (via python requests library or another library/tool/language). I am open to different ideas. You can find what I have already tried below:

1)

```
    import requests
    
    s=requests.Session()
    info = {'pass1':'a_password#38'}
    url1 = "http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=theKey&login=user_name"
    url2 = "http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-login.php?action=rp"
    
    r = s.get(url1)
    r2 = s.post(url1, data=info)
    r3 = requests.post(url2, data=info)
```

2. I have tried many versions of 1. In some of them for example I have not used the r and only used r2, some others I did not use r3. I believe that my problem comes from the fact that it is redirected to give me the form. You can find here the response I got when I used the print(r2.text), in case it is helpful:

   ```
        <!--[if IE 8]>
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie8" lang="en-US">
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if !(IE 8) ]><!-->
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Reset Password &lsaquo; wordPrSite3 &#8212; WordPress</title>
        <link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' /> <script> var userSettings = {"url":"\/wordpress_5_4_2_try3\/","uid":"0","time":"1621286619","secure":""}; </script> <script src='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-includes/js/utils.min.js?ver=5.4.6'></script> <script src='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp'></script> <script src='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script> <script> var _zxcvbnSettings = {"src":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress_5_4_2_try3\/wp-includes\/js\/zxcvbn.min.js"}; </script> <script src='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-includes/js/zxcvbn-async.min.js?ver=1.0'></script> <link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.4.6' media='all' /> <link rel='stylesheet' id='buttons-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=5.4.6' media='all' /> <link rel='stylesheet' id='forms-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-admin/css/forms.min.css?ver=5.4.6' media='all' /> <link rel='stylesheet' id='l10n-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-admin/css/l10n.min.css?ver=5.4.6' media='all' /> <link rel='stylesheet' id='login-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-admin/css/login.min.css?ver=5.4.6' media='all' />
        <meta name='robots' content='noindex,noarchive' />
        <meta name='referrer' content='strict-origin-when-cross-origin' />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
                </head>
        <body class="login no-js login-action-rp wp-core-ui  locale-en-us">
        <script type="text/javascript">
                document.body.className = document.body.className.replace('no-js','js');
        </script>
                <div id="login">
                <h1><a href="https://wordpress.org/">Powered by WordPress</a></h1>
        <p class="message reset-pass">Enter your new password below.</p>
                <form name="resetpassform" id="resetpassform" action="http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-login.php?action=resetpass" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                        <input type="hidden" id="user_login" value="user_name " autocomplete="off" />

                        <div class="user-pass1-wrap">
                                <p>
                                        <label for="pass1">New password</label>
                                </p>

                                <div class="wp-pwd">
                                        <input type="password" data-reveal="1" data-pw="t)&amp;NlDW$C7wgG^20" name="pass1" id="pass1" class="input password-input" size="24" value="" autocomplete="off" aria-describedby="pass-strength-result" />

                                        <button type="button" class="button button-secondary wp-hide-pw hide-if-no-js" data-toggle="0" aria-label="Hide password">
                                                <span class="dashicons dashicons-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <div id="pass-strength-result" class="hide-if-no-js" aria-live="polite">Strength indicator</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pw-weak">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="pw_weak" id="pw-weak" class="pw-checkbox" />
                                        <label for="pw-weak">Confirm use of weak password</label>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <p class="user-pass2-wrap">
                                <label for="pass2">Confirm new password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" class="input" size="20" value="" autocomplete="off" />
                        </p>

                        <p class="description indicator-hint">Hint: The password should be at least twelve characters long. To make it stronger, use upper and lower case letters, numbers, and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).</p>
                        <br class="clear" />

                                                <input type="hidden" name="rp_key" value="theKey" />
                        <p class="submit">
                                <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Reset Password" />
                        </p>
                </form>

                <p id="nav">
                        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-login.php">Log in</a>
                         | <a href="http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a> </p>
                                <p id="backtoblog"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/">
                &larr; Back to wordPrSite3              </a></p>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                try{document.getElementById('user_pass').focus();}catch(e){}
                if(typeof wpOnload=='function')wpOnload();
                </script>
                <script> var pwsL10n = {"unknown":"Password strength unknown","short":"Very weak","bad":"Weak","good":"Medium","strong":"Strong","mismatch":"Mismatch"}; </script> <script src='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-admin/js/password-strength-meter.min.js?ver=5.4.6'></script> <script src='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-includes/js/underscore.min.js?ver=1.8.3'></script> <script> var _wpUtilSettings = {"ajax":{"url":"\/wordpress_5_4_2_try3\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"}}; </script> <script src='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-includes/js/wp-util.min.js?ver=5.4.6'></script> <script> var userProfileL10n = {"warn":"Your new password has not been saved.","warnWeak":"Confirm use of weak password","show":"Show","hide":"Hide","cancel":"Cancel","ariaShow":"Show password","ariaHide":"Hide password"}; </script> <script src='http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-admin/js/user-profile.min.js?ver=5.4.6'></script>
        <script>
        /(trident|msie)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&document.getElementById&&window.addEventListener&&window.addEventListener("hashchange",function(){var t,e=location.hash.substring(1);/^[A-z0-9_-]+$/.test(e)&&(t=document.getElementById(e))&&(/^(?:a|select|input|button|textarea)$/i.test(t.tagName)||(t.tabIndex=-1),t.focus())},!1);
        </script>
                <div class="clear"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
   ```
3. After using postman and issuing only the post request I found that it does not redirect me to that page, but the preview instead looks like that:
   [Preview from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tLTH.png)

Because of this and after studying the r2.text, I changed my code and tried everything again using as info the:

```
info = {'pass1':'a_password#38', 'pass2':'a_password#38'}
```

The results were, unfortunately, the same and I am very confused about what exactly happens.

So, my questions are (with most important the 3rd one):

1. Why is the one simple post request not enough to submit the new password (or the password and the password confirmation)?
2. Why when I try it from my browser I get redirected to a page with 1 field (the one I showed in the first picture-link), while the postman and the code that is returned from a simple get request to the http://localhost/wordpress_5_4_2_try3/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=theKey&login=user_name implies that 2 fields are needed?
3. Do you have any idea of how to make it word either with requests or with another tool/library? I use Python requests but, of course, other languages are also welcome. My goal is to not use a tool that actually opens a browser, which takes a lot of time and more resources than I would prefer to give (I want to make some requests in parallel and measure the performance).

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What's your exact question about this? What is the **specific** problem you are facing?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I edited the post by adding 3 points/questions at the end. If anything is not clear, please let me know (I am new in all of these).

Comment: Please share more details. "Why is the post request not enough to submit the new password" - what does "not enough" mean?

Comment: I mean that the response I receive from the post request is the exact same page like the one I requested to. So, it does not seem to redirect to the page that normally the browser redirects us to when we reset the password. In addition, to make sure that my post request does not reset the password, I tried to login with the password I provided using the post request, and as expected it does not work (login fails).